# Overriding vim keyword syntax in after/syntax file

Tags: javascript, vim, vim-plugin, vim-syntax-highlighting

So I am working in a javascript project. And I have some code like this:
[image]

I am using the [vim-javascript](https://github.com/pangloss/vim-javascript) plugin and it has these lines on syntax/javascript.vim:

```
syntax keyword jsOperator delete instanceof typeof void new in of
syntax match   jsOperator /[\!\|\&\+\-\<\>\=\%\/\*\~\^]\{1}/
```

But I would like to add different syntax to these files in my after/syntax file, something like `jsNew` to `new` keyword so I could highlight it with different color. I am trying commands like this:

```
syntax keyword jsNew new containedin='jsOperator'
```

But it is not working. What would be the correct way to highlight the `new` keyword with no change to the syntax file that comes with the vim-javascript plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had success with these commands in my *../after/syntax/javascript.vim*:

```
syntax keyword jsNew new
syntax cluster jsExpression add=jsNew
hi def link jsNew Special
```

now the 'new' keyword is highlighted with the color for the highlight group: Special.